# Fragment change during WebView load causes crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I am using a WebView inside a fragment. The user can switch between fragments using a navigation bar.

The following code runs a loading image while the WebView is loading and hides the loading image when the loading process is finished. It works very well except that the application crashes most of the time when switching to another fragment ***during*** the WebView loading process.

```
myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        // Shows loading image during WebView load
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            getView().findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            getView().findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
```

Help on why the crash might occur would be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you supply the crash stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            getView().findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            getView().findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

You change the fragment before page loads and in `onPageFinished()` you are trying to get an image and set its visibility which is no more exists. Better to make a week reference of fragment, and in your onPageFinished, first check weather your `webview fragment` is destroyed or available. If available then proceed to set visibility otherwise ignore.